# Philosophy is useless for me!

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

What environment is best suited to allow for reprogramming of the subconscious? Let me explain, i am studying Friedrich Nietzsche, the ideas and argument he is presenting is overwhelming my old ideas to the point i can not help but believe them. The issue is my consciousness believe the arguments but my subconscious still hold on and "react" to the opposite. Kind of like i do not believe in religion but can't stop praying. Naturly this takes time but it has beem over four years and i still can't shake my old logic which makes philosophy more of a hobby then anything useful. We know your environment shape you, so how can i use this to better reinforce my ideas?

Comment: Nietzsche talked a lot about doing things he didn't do either, so maybe you are following him better than you realise!

Comment: May i ask for sources on this? Would be glad to read more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a neuroscience or psychology answer, but its effects should apply to philosophical thinking as well. The brain has different modes or systems for different types of processing, as for example *sequential symbolic* versus *parallel spacial*. Concepts learned early in life probably rely at least in part on non-verbal systems. These deep-seated understandings likely are not going to go away or readily subside in the face of linguistic arguments alone. Not only that, but [System 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_process_theory) (unconscious, automatic) learning in general is resistant to change.

**Tip 1: Use the same mental modality as existing automatic thoughts**. If telling yourself in words to act or think a new way is not working, perhaps try visualising without words. If visual is not enough, try thinking in tactile or bodily sensation. During this process and while initiating action, you may in fact need to suppress words entirely.

**Tip 2: Find novel ways to see new concepts or actions**. Long-standing habits have been reinforced over and again from many perspectives. To compete, new ways may need a collection of independent yet compatible views. Consider expanding your mental horizons with other authors of similar core sentiment.

**Tip 3: Find your desire and activate your emotion**. If you cannot remember why you want the new habit or viewpoint to take hold, the mental inertia of old ways is going to interfere with progress. You may need to find and keep that happy thought of what you expect to gain from this change.

**Tip 4: Slow down for automatic thoughts**. System 1 thoughts come forth whenever the right buttons are pressed, which may include a combination of chemical, sensory, and mental cues. You can think of it like an automatic file retrieval system. The problem is going too fast will prevent reflection on whether you truly want to take that old path. Generally, the older the learned response, the faster it comes. But if you slow down, you can catch yourself and wait a second for the newer wisdom to shine through. In your environment you want at least (a) some intentional cues to prime your newer thinking and (b) enough relaxation to allow your mind to step out of any fight-or-flight impulsivity preventing self-reflection.

**Bonus: Forget your past and start new**. Like in addiction, the presence of a simple cue can invoke unwanted ways of the past. In this sense, mental reminders help place the mental set from which you operate. Recall of [context sensitive memories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_(memory)#Context) can be strengthened by environments similar, even in scent, to where the memory became. There is a reason many cults remove reminders of one's past. For maximum change, you may have to brainwash yourself by replacing your world.

An important note about mental modality is that even thoughts that seem linguistic in nature, particularly abstract thoughts, may be processed initially (if not continually) through auxiliary perception systems. This phenomenon is known as the [semantic vacuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideasthesia). If you get lucky, a new idea may happen to use the same brain system as the old manner; but still, forcing a given mental modality, such as visual or tactile thinking, may help to unstuck your mind.

Comment: Sorry i was late in responding. This is EXACTLY what i am looking for. This gives me more to research.

Comment: @SQPRIIV -- On the topic of changing one's environment, a popular alternative is to change one's reaction to the environment, especially through [states of trance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trance), such as those arrived through [meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation) or trance music. One particularly sought state is that of [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)). In these states, adverse effects of extraneous stimuli are often minimised, which can allow better focus.

Comment: @SQPRIIV -- Also, if you have never *properly* learned about it but have some time, I highly recommend reading the page on [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance). It goes beyond common understanding and closely relates to changes and struggles in changing behaviour and belief.

Answer (score 0):

You are in good company.
Ironically, it is often taught like old toast.
Philosophers must reinvent themselves or have their relevance calved every generation.  I defended my thesis on Foucault 40 years ago and have been informed by my sophomore aged son that Michel has been reclassified from revolutionary sage to ridiculous. Sigh.
It is a broad and  uniquely discrete discipline to dismiss categorically. There is something for everyone but you do need to grin and bear it thru the the classical parade that defines undergrad.
You'll earn an intellectual tool chest that will afford you an edge in any career. (teach a man to fish...)
It might help to focus on the tangible craft of Aristotelian logic.
He was a pretty cool dude.
You will never lose a "cognitive" based argument with your spouse, boss or child, unless, you weren't paying attention and married a lawyer or religious despot.
I'd like to see a B.A in Geology do that.
Aristotle did not consider philosophy an academic discipline at all*. I humbly agree. He felt philosophy was the necessary "process' that came BEFORE any serious academic endeavor.
Maybe ask your prof to loosen his syllabus at the risk of him teaching you. good luck
*source missing